# Why can I only get 300 names when I execute this web scraping code?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

profile_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22third+party+risk+management%22+OR+%22supply+chain+risk%22&sca_esv=563003270&sxsrf=AB5stBgxZpVCl25X4zUTzTHRoWclocBm1w%3A1693985864737&ei=SCz4ZJjPLNb8hwOFqp-oDQ&ved=0ahUKEwiYk-ONvZWBAxVW_mEKHQXVB9UQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22third+party+risk+management%22+OR+%22supply+chain+risk%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiTnNpdGU6bGlua2VkaW4uY29tL2luLyBBTkQgInRoaXJkIHBhcnR5IHJpc2sgbWFuYWdlbWVudCIgT1IgInN1cHBseSBjaGFpbiByaXNrIkgAUABYAHAAeACQAQCYAQCgAQCqAQC4AQPIAQD4AQHiAwQYACBB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp"

driver.get(profile_url)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")


count=100
while count>1:
    load_more = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id=\"botstuff\"]/div/div[3]/div[4]/a[1]/h3/div/span[1]")
    load_more.click() 
    count-=1
    time.sleep(2)

names = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "h3")

len(names)

driver.quit()
```

I wanted to get 1000 names but I only get 300. Next I would like to get all the URLs of the gathered names, what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could be useful:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
profile_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22third+party+risk+management%22+OR+%22supply+chain+risk%22&sca_esv=563003270&sxsrf=AB5stBgxZpVCl25X4zUTzTHRoWclocBm1w%3A1693985864737&ei=SCz4ZJjPLNb8hwOFqp-oDQ&ved=0ahUKEwiYk-ONvZWBAxVW_mEKHQXVB9UQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22third+party+risk+management%22+OR+%22supply+chain+risk%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiTnNpdGU6bGlua2VkaW4uY29tL2luLyBBTkQgInRoaXJkIHBhcnR5IHJpc2sgbWFuYWdlbWVudCIgT1IgInN1cHBseSBjaGFpbiByaXNrIkgAUABYAHAAeACQAQCYAQCgAQCqAQC4AQPIAQD4AQHiAwQYACBB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp"
driver.get(profile_url)
# Define the desired number to scrap
desired_count = 1000
current_count = 0

while current_count < desired_count:
    try:
        # Find all the name elements h3
        names = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "h3")
        
        for name in names[current_count:]:
            name_text = name.text
            name.click()
            # Wait for the profile page to load
            time.sleep(2)
            # Get the current window to handle
            current_window = driver.current_window_handle
            # Switch to the new tab that opened
            for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
                if window_handle != current_window:
                    driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
                    break
            # Get the URL of the LinkedIn profile
            profile_url = driver.current_url
            # Close the LinkedIn profile tab
            driver.close()
            # Switch back to the original search results tab
            driver.switch_to.window(current_window)
            # Update current count
            current_count += 1
            if current_count >= desired_count:
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
    
    # Scroll down to load more results
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
    time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```